# NodeJs: Redirect with data not explicitly visible in the url

Tags: node.js, http, express

**[1]** I need to redirect a user from a link in an email, along with some data to a webpage.

**[2]** The data to be sent **must not be visible** in the url, i.e. the query string approach that goes like

```
res.redirect('www.something.com?data=123');
```

I need to send data in the POST-like format, keeping the url clear.

Comment: The only option is to put a form in email but this is considered a security risk and requires confirmation from the client.

Comment: You could also store the query data in a database, map it to a short id, and use that as the query string instead. You're still using a query string, but it's much shorter, e.g. `URL?u=1a71bf0` -> `{user: 123, campaign: 193, etc.}`

Comment: But the real question is: why? The way you've trying to do is plain and simple.

Comment: @freakish I just wanted to know if this is possible. So far I have stumbled across using sessions for achieving the same results but that would only help in making the server bloated.